# can i change VIMRUNTIM if i want to move/usr/share/vim/vim71 to other path?

Tags: editor, vim, vim-plugin

if yes, how to change such variable?

should i modify vimrc? but vimrc is in $VIMTIME, if i changed it, how vim find it?

i maybe have lots copies of VIMRUNTIME, and i hope that i can switch to different VIMRUNTIMEs easily, how to make this done.

anybody here who have ever tried to do this?

btw, there are lots of .vim files inside $VIMRUNTIME, are they all vim plugins? is .vim files all writen in vimscript? what vimscript can do and what it cannot? why not all vim plugins implemented using .vim? since i find some vim plugin also use script language such as perl or python...

Answer (score 3):

The gory details are documented under `:help startup`, but you rarely need to modify `$VIMRUNTIME`. You didn't mention why you would want to do this, but it's probably a bad idea.

If you don't want to set the `VIMRUNTIME` environment variable in the shell from which you launch Vim, you can modify it in a user-specific `~/.vimrc` (via `:let $VIMRUNTIME = '/path/to/it'`), because that one is read before the system-wide configuration.

The runtime files contain the help documents, default configuration, filetype detections and syntax highlightings. You can add your own extensions (e.g. downloads from http://www.vim.org) in `~/.vim/...`. As I said, there should be no need to mess with the system-wide runtime; this is managed by your system's package management.